# Can I work around bash disabling errexit after BASH_ENV invocation?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to enable `errexit` by default. (Yes, I know that this is contentious; please consider whether it's a good idea or not outside the scope of the question).

I've tried triggering this from a file named in the `BASH_ENV` environment variable; however, in `shell.c`, it resets the value of this flag after `run_startup_files()` is complete.

Is there any mechanism -- such as a DEBUG trap -- to trigger the execution of arbitrary code (such as code that reenables the `errexit` flag) *before* the first line of a script executed by a noninteractive shell is invoked?

Comment: i.e. do you want to know when a first command is executed?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy eh? you open a interactive shell and run ./temp.sh (since temp is in the current folder) and this spawns a non interactive shell right?

Comment: @sKwa I want to know when the first command in the script is ready to be executed not when it is executed

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay whatever amount of configuration.. its still configuration :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have the DEBUG trap in a script pointed to by $BASH_ENV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164794/discussion-between-sam-thomas-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Haha... Thank you for that. I was doing that myself just after I typed a message for you in chat

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No Problems. Thanks for the edit